# Как решить проблему с кодировкой js

Tags: javascript, кодировка, visual-studio-code

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Начал изучать язык не давно, просьба объяснить простым языком.

Comment: на вскидку.. поставьте кодировку вашего файла в UTF-8) да и код в файле не оч коректный) + VScode docker dev просто отличная штука..

Comment: Подскажите как?

Comment: В нижней строке VS Code вы увидите метку UTF-8. Щелкните ее, чтобы открыть панель действий, и выберите команду Сохранить с кодировкой. Теперь вы можете выбрать новую кодировку для этого файла. правда у вас уже ЮТФ) мб win cp-1251.. но это плохой вариант)
Простите, я работаю в линукс и такого никогда не встречал.. еще в далеком 2010м разве что

Comment: Сделал как вы написали, только win cp-1251 не было выбрал 1252. Запустил, прикрепил скриншот не помогло

Comment: Как написал выше, win 1251 и тд сейчас врятли кто использует, основная кодировка UTF-8, судя по консоле, кодировка страдает в выводе иформационного сообщения node) вставьте какой-то более коректный код, например `console.log('Русский текст')`

Comment: У вас  не установлено [NodeJS](https://nodejs.org/en/).

Comment: @Oliver Patterson NodeJS установлен скриншот прикрепил.

Comment: @Jour как вы написали работает, но хотелось бы разобраться почему не работает как я написал?